# How to find occurance of mxprod|nlsoprdc inside multiple file in a directory?

Tags: grep, find, xargs

How can I:

- Search for a particular pattern in the content of files in a directory and its subdirectory
- And list the filename if it has particular pattern?

Answer (score 1):

use: the `-l` and `-r` flags:

```
grep -l -r pattern
```

> [man grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)
>
> -l, --files-with-matches
>       Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed. The scanning will
>   stop on the first match. (-l is specified by POSIX .)
>
> -R, -r, --recursive
>       Read all files under each directory, recursively; this is equivalent to the -d recurse option.

Comment: Hi Yaron, thanks for the reply... I  am using find . -type f -exec egrep "mxprod|nlsoprdc" {}  /dev/null \; and i am getting the matches further i need to zip all the files listed with the above command and delete.. pls help

Comment: Hi Yaron tried your answer getting error like : grep: illegal option -- r
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . . pls help

Comment: @kavya - `egrep` has the option of `-l` which output only the name of the files it found, so you can use the `-l` flag. regarding your new question -I'd open a new question * - I've a list of files - resulted from `find` command, how can I use it to zip/tar the files and delete the original files*